# NGINX, proxy cache and dynamic URI

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, node.js

I have a NGINX reverse proxy that sits in front of a node.js server (express). With a pretty basic configuration. The problem I'm running into is with NGINX's proxy caching feature. Here's the setup.

```
http {
  proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/zone1 levels=1:2
                     keys_zone=zone1:10m max_size=10g
                     inactive=10m use_temp_path off;
  ...
  server {

    ...
    location /assets/ {
      proxy_pass $frontend$request_uri;
      proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
      proxy_cache zone1;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
      access_log off;
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Our URI for assets looks like this `/assets/1.0.0/(.css|.js|.png|etc..)`. We update the version in the URI during build time so it does change frequently, which I'm assuming should invalidate the `proxy_cache_key` and NGINX should go back upstream to get the **new** assets. But this never happens. I'm just left with my un-styled html page.

Once I clear the cached files manually and issue a `nginx -s reload` all is fine again. Am I missing something? Many thanks!

Comment: Where you define `$scheme` variable?

Comment: @AlexanderT `$scheme` is a built in variable.

Comment: May be there is cached pages with old assets url? And nginx still receiving requests with old URI?

Comment: @AlexanderT I thought that may have been the case too, but. I don't cache html so when the user receives the new document it makes a request to the new assets URL.

Comment: How exactly does the asset URL change between versions?

Comment: For example `/assets/1.0.0/bundle.js` -> `/assets/1.0.1/bundle.js`

Comment: It's seems as though you have an extra initial quote in your cache key, is that in your actual file or just from the edit pasted here? Also, have you watched the `error.log`?

Comment: @Joshua Sorry, that's a typo. Just edited.